# Authentication In Laravel With Multi Auth

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5, laravel-middleware

i am just learning the laravel version 5.4.
i just made a simple blog post application using laravel with an website and admin panel

So in navbar which is common for front side code looks like below

```
@if (Auth::guest())
    <li><a href="{{ route('login') }}">Login</a></li>
    <li><a href="{{ route('register') }}">Register</a></li>
@else
    <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">
            {{ Auth::user()->vName }} <span class="caret"></span>
        </a>
    </li>
```

And In controller

```
class PostController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        //$this->middleware('auth:user'); << i also tried thi
        $this->middleware('auth:user')->except('index','show');
    }
```

So the problem is i wants to allow all users to read blog post without login
but if i add this middleware than user cant access this page without the login.

than i also tried to put `except()` keyword. after adding this it works but problem is in navbar it is still showing `Login/Register` instead showing logout button and profile name.

Comment: Hi TarangP, Middleware is designed to fire before or after the controller.  You can apply middleware a controller (intermediate skill) but I think for learning - you should keep your middleware on your routes.  Also, in your case, you want "web" middleware with your auth middleware so that your sessions are running.

Comment: Updated my answer with correct middleware you should use

Answer (score 0):

> Updated: refactor your controller middleware to

```
$this->middleware('auth:web,user', ['except' => ['index', 'show']]);
```

And try register a new user

Comment: Thanks for the answer.i've updated the question.now the problem is `Auth::user()->vName ` is i am getting `NULL`. So how can i retrieve data from user

Comment: It's showing `NULL`. and that's the problem where. if i retrive data in `Auth::User()` than it will be works fine

Comment: can you add a snipet of your user table columns to your question

Comment: @TarangP updated my answer this should resolve your question

Comment: i know but still i am struggling for this issue.i still didnt find the solution. still `User` is returning `NULL`

Comment: Did you check your User model?

Comment: Yes. i've added very cleverly

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223636/discussion-between-jelly-bean-and-tarangp).